# i want to use stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30 in java command line

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

[image: java -mx100m edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -sentFile input.txt -collapsedTree -CCprocessed -parseTree -parserFile englishPCFG.ser.gz]

when i use this command

> java -mx100m edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure
>   -sentFile input.txt -collapsedTree -CCprocessed -parseTree -parserFile englishPCFG.ser.gz it return this Error: unable to find or load main
>   class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure

and when i use this command

> java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure
>   -sentFile input.txt -collapsedTree -CCprocessed -parseTree -parserFile englishPCFG.ser.gz it retruns

```
Loading parser from serialized file englishPCFG.ser.gz ...
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readStreamFromString(IOUtils.java:396)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromSerializedFile(LexicalizedParser.java:599)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:394)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:181)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.loadParser(GrammaticalStructure.java:1394)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.main(GrammaticalStructure.java:1645)
Loading parser from text file englishPCFG.ser.gz java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:591)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromTextFile(LexicalizedParser.java:533)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:396)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:181)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.loadParser(GrammaticalStructure.java:1394)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.main(GrammaticalStructure.java:1645)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.main(GrammaticalStructure.java:1655)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.main(GrammaticalStructure.java:1652)
```

i don't know where is the problem and how to use this library

Comment: Which version of [Stanford CoreNLP](https://search.maven.org/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp) are you using?

Comment: Can you run `dir` command first? Looks like `englishPCFG.ser.gz` is not present in `C:\Users\yasser\Desktop\java\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30`.

Comment: i am using 3.5.1 version

Comment: And why not the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply the resource's full path in the command.

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz
```

When Java tries to find something, it looks for that path in all of the jar files in the CLASSPATH.  Also the `-cp "*"` will only work if you are executing the command in the directory with all of the `.jar` files.